# Padding between pagination control and table

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX table with pagination control on which I applied padding.

```
pagination.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5));
```

[image: screenshot]

I added padding, but in this case the pagination control and table are very close to each other. How I can add some space between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried and it's odd that this doesn't work. A quick solution / workaround is to put both the TableView and the Pagination into a VBox and add spacing.

Like this:

```
    public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            TableView tv = new TableView();
            Pagination pg = new Pagination();

            VBox root = new VBox();
            root.setSpacing(10);
            root.getChildren().addAll( tv, pg);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also solved this with BorderPane. Look like a bug?

Comment: At least it doesn't look like something one would expect.